# How can an existential quantifier "quantify out" certain variable instances?

Tags: logic, notation, quantifiers

In ["Handbook of Model Checking"](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-10575-8) (p. 37, 2.2.4 Algorithms), the following operator is presented (along with 3 similar ones):

$$\mathrm{prime}(\tau)=\exists\mathscr{V}.(\tau\land({\bigwedge}_{v\in\mathscr{V}}v=v'))$$

From the text, it seems that this is supposed to replace each instance of a variable $v\in\mathscr{V}$ that occurs in the assertion $\tau$ with its primed counterpart $v'\in\mathscr{V'}$.

For example, $\mathrm{prime}(x=3)$ should be equivalent to $x'=3$.

Note that $\mathscr{V}$ and $\mathscr{V'}$ are fixed in this context to be sets which contain all of the variables in the domain of discourse and their primed counterparts, respectively ($\mathscr{V}=\{x\}$ and $\mathscr{V'}=\{x'\}$ in the above example).

I'm having trouble understanding how exactly the existential quantifier works in this context.

To follow the above example, with $\tau$ defined as $x=3$ and $\mathscr{V}$ defined as $\{x\}$, we have (by simple variable replacement):

$$\mathrm{prime}(x=3)=\exists\{x\}.((x=3)\land(x=x'))$$

Or, equivalently:

$$\mathrm{prime}(x=3)=\exists\{x\}.(x=x'=3)$$

This is where I'm stuck. The text says that the existential quantifier "quantifies out" variables in $\mathscr{V}$. I expect from context that this allows us to "remove" the $x$ instance on the right hand side (as I expect the result to simplify to $x'=3$), but I don't understand how/why this is possible. What am I missing? Perhaps this example is too simple? This pattern appears in several other works in this space (model checking) and while I can accept simple operators like $\mathrm{prime}$ at face value, some of the more complex ones are harder to understand, and I feel this is holding me back.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $\exists x(x=x'=3)$ is equivalent to $x'=3$. Sort of confusingly, the "$\exists\mathscr V$" is shorthand for a string of $\exists$ quantifiers using all the variable names in $\mathscr V$ (as opposed to claiming existence of a set named $\mathscr V$).

Comment: I suppose that $\tau$ must be a *term* (i.e. a "name", like $2$ or $x+1$) because we use it as argument of "predicate" $\text {prime}$. Having said that, we can easily check that $\text {prime}(x) \equiv \exists x' (\text {prime}(x') \land x'=x)$.